# What does stride mean in a bitmap? Small colorpicker code with comments specifying the line in question

Tags: c#, color-picker

What does the `stride` parameter do in the `CopyPixels` method?
Feel free to help with the other lines that have a comment if you wish.

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = ColorSquare.Source as BitmapSource;
            if (bitmapSource != null)
            {
                double x = Mouse.GetPosition(ColorSquare).X;

                //This next line is confusing. It seems like I'm just dividing an image by itself
                //say the image width is 4 and since I'm using it as the bitmap source the
                //both the PixelWidth and the ActualWidth will = 4, right? Basically x *= 1;
                x *= bitmapSource.PixelWidth / ColorSquare.ActualWidth;

                if ((int)x > bitmapSource.PixelWidth - 1)
                    x = bitmapSource.PixelWidth - 1;
                else if (x < 0) x = 0;
                double y = Mouse.GetPosition(ColorSquare).Y;
                y *= bitmapSource.PixelHeight / ColorSquare.ActualHeight;
                if ((int)y > bitmapSource.PixelHeight - 1)
                    y = bitmapSource.PixelHeight - 1;
                else if (y < 0) y = 0;
                CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(bitmapSource, new Int32Rect((int)x, (int)y, 1, 1));
                byte[] pixels = new byte[4];

                //What is the stride and why does it need to be 4?
                cb.CopyPixels(pixels, 4, 0);
                if (pixels[3] == byte.MaxValue)
                {
                    //So it seems we are passing all 4 pixels we copied earlier into the array
                    //here. This would be the Alpha,Red,Green,Blue of a color. So is that what stride does?
                    color = Color.FromArgb(pixels[3], pixels[2], pixels[1], pixels[0]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: My goodness what's up with the downvotes. The documentation doesn't have any info on stride it just says that it's the second parameter for CopyPixels. Don't like having magic code and I would like to understand what that particular parameter does

Comment: _The documentation doesn't have any info on stride_ Oh yeah? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride) . First hit with [c# stride](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=c%23+stride) - Note that __you are expected to do at least some research__ before coming here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, it's 4 because you are asking for 4 pixels (it seems). However stride (as referred to in the method parameter) is just referring to how many pixels you want.

However, let's dig deeper.

*Stride* (Line stride) is essentially the length of a scan line in memory (padded or otherwise). Meaning, if you had to iterate over a 1 dimensional array of an image, you can use it to calculate pixel and lines (among other things)

[image]

Which is opposed to a Pixel Stride, the amount of bytes a pixel takes up in memory. A 32 bits per pixel image, will have 4 bytes (32 bits) or Uint per pixel.

**Summary**

- *pixel address* — a pixel address in memory
- *pixel depth* — the number of bits per pixel (containing valuable information)
- *pixel stride* — the number of bytes occupied in memory by a pixel of an image
- *data begin* — the address of the first image pixel in memory
- *channels* — the number of image channels (3 for an RGB-image)
- *channel_address* — the address of a particular pixel channel in memory
- *height* — the image height in pixels
- *width* — the image width in pixels
- *line stride* — the number of bytes occupied in memory by a line of an image

---

**Additional Resources**

[CopyPixels(Array, Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_Imaging_BitmapSource_CopyPixels_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

> Copies the bitmap pixel data into an array of pixels with the
> specified stride, starting at the specified offset.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - pixels - `Array` The destination array.
> - stride - `Int32` The stride of the bitmap.
> - offset - `Int32` The pixel location where copying starts.

Comment: Ok so in my example does that mean that I'm actually storing 4 pixels into my array?

Comment: @luigi because you are just asking for 4 pixels in this case, as to what the code is doing or why, i have no idea

Comment: Thank you buddy. I think I get it now. I appreciate it